# babel, frenchb and em dash

Tags: spacing, typography, babel, french

If I'm not wrong, in French the em-dashes, typeset with `---` in LaTeX, are usually treated like the guillemets as far as non-breaking spaces go. An "opening" em-dash must be followed by a non-breaking space, while a "closing" em-dash must be preceded by a non-breaking space.

`[french]{babel}` doesn't apply this rule, so I ended up making my own macros:

```
\newcommand{\ocadr}{\mbox{---~}}
\newcommand{\fcadr}{\mbox{~---}}
```

Is there a better way to ensure these non-breaking spaces?

**Edit:**

Here is a minimal example to justify the use of `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

\parbox{9cm}{\textsc{
Dieu se sert des epreuves pour nous montrer nos c\oe{}urs,
 afin de pouvoir nous purifier et nous faire ensuite entrer
 dans le pays de la benediction ---~physiquement et spirituellement.
}}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: em bad newline]

Whereas with `\mbox` around the `---~`, I get:

[image: em good newline]

**Nota:**

I kept the `\textsc` because it's a case that I know produces this effect with the given size of the `\parbox`.

Comment: I suspect that 'cadratin' is a French term: looks like an em-dash to me.

Comment: I was always understood that in french typography it is space, en dash, space (i.e, em dash is not normally used).

Comment: @Yiannis: according to Wikipedia (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret#Tiret_long, in French), em dash has to be used, but en dash is sometimes preferred (although the source for that is missing in the article).

Comment: OK, I see where the break is coming from. I've updated my answer: I would keep only the necessary material inside a box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see that the `\mbox` is needed as the ligature inserts a `\discretionary`. However, I'd keep the space out of the box if I were you. So

```
\newcommand*{\ocadr}{\mbox{---}~}
\newcommand*{\fcadr}{\unskip~---}
```

using the primitives `\unskip` to avoid any additional space (the opening macro should skip spaces in any case) and the `\mbox` to prevent a break after the opening material would seem best.

Comment: I added an `\mbox`because I had a case were a newline was added right after the em in spite of the non-breaking space.

Comment: @Joseph: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/3f19c73d77af7a4e/?pli=1 mentions the newline issue.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm actually leaning towards `\mbox{---}\,` to make the non-breaking space smaller after the dash.

Comment: @Raphink: In that case, use `\mbox{---}\nobreak\,\nobreak` to ensure that the em-dash sticks to the following material.