# Avoid line break between em-dash and the next word

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, spanish

I'm writing a text in Spanish, and I have a phrase wrote between em-dashes (that work like parentheses). The problem is that if the "opening" em-dash is too near the end of the line, then it may happen that it remains in that line but the next word falls to the next:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a leo quis 
libero ---accumsan vulputate---. Praesent pretium dapibus est interdum 
hendrerit.
```

[image: bad result]

What I need to get in this example, is the opening em-dash and its next word to be in the same line, like this:

[image: good result]

where I had to use

```
\mbox{---accumsan}
```

Is there a simple way to make LaTeX not to break the opening em-dash with its next word, and also the ending em-dash with its previous word?

Comment: I am not sure about the specifics of the spanish language when compared to french. Could you have a look if this link to a similar question works for you as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16156/babel-frenchb-and-em-dash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are writing in Spanish, you surely are using the `spanish` option for `babel`. If this is the case, then you can use the shorthand `"+--` to prevent a possible line break. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

%wrong output:
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a leo quis 
 ---accumsan vulputate---. Praesent pretium dapibus est interdum 
hendrerit.

%right output:
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a leo quis 
 "+--accumsan vulputate"+--. Praesent pretium dapibus est interdum 
hendrerit.

\end{document}
```

[image]​

Another option is to use the `\nobreakdash` command implemented by the `amsmath` package; this command suppresses any line break after the dash (or hyphen). Of course, if you are going to use this a lot, you can define a new command to simplify the writing. In the following example I defined two commands using `\nobreakdash`: the first variant will prevent hyphenation of the word following the em-dash; the second variant will allow normal hyphenation in the following word:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\RayaN{\nobreakdash---}
\newcommand\Rayan{\nobreakdash---\hspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a leo quis 
 ---accumsan vulputate---. Praesent pretium dapibus est interdum 
hendrerit.

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a leo quis 
 \RayaN accumsan vulputate\RayaN. Praesent pretium dapibus est interdum 
hendrerit.

\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a leo quis 
 \Rayan accumsan vulputate\Rayan. Praesent pretium dapibus est interdum 
hendrerit.

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest the addition of [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) to accommodate for the following scenario the requires an end-of-command-sequence space: `...a leo quis \Rayan accumsan vulputate\Rayan lorem ipsum...`. This OP did mention that the em-dashes act like parentheses.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo, it worked perfectly using `"+--` with babel (which I was already using, as you correctly thought).

Answer (score 2):

You can set `\exhyphenpenalty=10000`. After this, the hyphen-like places (generated by `-` or `--` or `---` are unbreakable.

Advantage: The setting can be done only once at beginning of the document. You needn't to change the markup of the document.

Disadvantage: the word immediately followed after `---` is not hyphenated. If this brings the problem, you can insert explicitly hyphen points in this word by `\-`.

Comment: You should note that also compound words will not be broken at the hyphen.